# How can I hit small mouse targets more reliably in my multi-monitor setup?

Tags: google-chrome, multiple-monitors, windows-11

I work on a laptop with an external display, and I recently tried moving it from side-by-side to top-and-bottom.  I like the ergonomics, but it breaks [Fitt's Law](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/fitts-law/) by removing the "infinite edge" that menu bars rely on.  Picking out individual browser tabs at the top of my bottom display is a particular difficulty, as is hitting the Windows toolbar at the bottom the top display.

I dimly remember using a Linux desktop window manager that introduced a "bump" between monitors to solve this, your cursor stopped at the edge between displays unless you approached it with sufficient speed to overcome "inertia".  I found a bunch of articles about `MouseMonitorEscapeSpeed` on Windows but it looks like that might have been phased out around Windows 10 (I'm on 11 now), and anyway most of the content is people who *don't* want a "speed bump" and are trying to get rid of it.

My preference would be to reintroduce this inertia between displays, either as a registry edit or with 3rd party software.  Making the browser tab-bar taller would also help, and honestly I'm open to any suggestions from people with similar problems.

Comment: You could always go to the display settings and do this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDKcG.png

Comment: You mean that the tabs are squeezed-together and become smaller and harder to hit? You may set a minimal tab width as described in [this link](https://www.makeuseof.com/set-minimum-tab-width-firefox-chrome/), but you might then need to scroll the tabs. There exist extensions that can make tabs-management easier in this case.

Comment: I should be clear, it's less about the width and more about the height.  My comment about Fitt's Law is because normally you can "throw" your mouse at the top of the display and it always stops, so you don't have to be careful about vertical travel.  The tabs are harder to hit because you have to stop before the pointer spills over into the display above it.

Comment: @Mokubai that's very clever, I'm going to try it for a while and see how I like it.  To save a click, or in case the image goes away: they suggested positioning the monitors so that they only touch at the corner, which means you have to "throw" your mouse top-left or top-right to get from one monitor to the other.

Comment: 1. Make tab *groups*, so fewer tabs show at one time: https://www.google.com/chrome/tips/ 2. Use the *keyboard* to select tabs: https://www.howtogeek.com/807523/12-keyboard-shortcuts-for-tabs-in-google-chrome/ Ctrl+Tab and Ctrl+Shift+Tab to cycle through them; Ctrl+ *n*, where *n* is a digit, 1 through 8, to select one.

Comment: Would you consider putting your browser tabs and/or taskbar on the side instead of the top?

Comment: Using an extension like [Tree Style Tab](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/tree-style-tab/oicakdoenlelpjnkoljnaakdofplkgnd) would allow selecting a tab via the keyboard from a clearly displayed list, so no mouse movement is required. Would that be a solution?

Comment: Tab groups wouldn't really address the height issue (i.e., overshooting the top of the window), but the comment about tree-style tabs reminded me that Chrome now has a native tab list dropdown.  I just checked and it has a keyboard shortcut displayed when you open it (CTRL+SHIFT+A on Windows) so maybe that would be a good habit rather than clicking tabs in the top bar.  So far, the suggestion from @Mokubai has actually been working out well, and obviates the need for tab UI changes.

Comment: @Coderer I have converted my comment to an answer. Feel free to leave it unaccepted as it is not quite a "great" solution but rather a "working with the tools we have" kind of deal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always go to the display settings and shift your monitors around to achieve something like this. You would probably want som small area of overlap but otherwise you could make it so that there is only a small zone where you can have a mouse cursor transition from one screen to another.

[image]

You can move monitors like this by simply clicking and dragging them into a position you like.

I personally would find it somewhat frustrating, but it does achieve a goal of limiting mouse movement between screens unless absolutely desired.

Moving actual application windows should be easier as you can use <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> or <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right Arrow</kbd> to move them between screens.

Comment: I've used this since your original comment went up, but with "2" to the left of "1" instead of the right, which lets me "fling" the mouse to top-right of the primary display to hit the "X" (close) button.  My only complaint is that it's maybe too effective, I sometimes have to try to jump between monitors 2-3 times before I get it right.  Re: "small area of overlap", I tried that but as soon as you have any at all, Windows "helpfully" jumps the mouse from anywhere on the edge.  The "stopping" effect requires that they only touch at the corner.